# setup teamcity with .core, run command fails

Tags: .net-core, teamcity

I am trying to migrate from Jenkins to Teamcity 2018

So far I have 4 build steps:

1. Dotnet restore
2. dotnet build
3. dotnet run
4. dotnet test

When teamcity runs 3rd step, it fails.
it tries to run :

```
 dotnet.exe run --project .\Prime.csproj @D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\5d23e7ecee784cabb12baefd7175c67d.rsp
```

and it gives error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Unrecognized argument format: '@D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\5d23e7ecee784cabb12baefd7175c67d.rsp'.
```

I think, it because dotnet cli doesn't accept the @ part..

Have anyone seen such error before?

Solution has 2 projects: Prime (the main code) and a tests project with all the tests. The tests project runs just with with 'dotnet test' command

Using dotnet core 2.0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way forward which I found is to run .core app in Docker.
So, you need to publish the app to a folder and then put that code into a docker image and then set up your test project to run against docker instance of the app.